# Defensive semicolon in JShint

Tags: javascript, jshint

According to the [bugfix release: r04](http://www.jshint.com/blog/2012-01-08/release-r04/) and the relative [commit](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/commit/a47843fb8efd863b26106586382c765cdec9f7da) on Github, a support for **defensive semicolon** was previously added to *JShint*.

```
/* jshint white: true */
;(function () {
    "use strict";
})();
```

But I'm still getting this error:

> *expected '(' to have an indentation at 1 instead at 2*

I'm using the default JShint options (ASI mode *false*), and I'm overwriting these ones

```
"jshint_options": {
    "browser": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "mootools": true,
    "node": true,
    "debug": true,
    "devel": true,
    "expr": true,
    "white": true
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: @user2246674 i get the same error! i'd like to keep the semicolon for concatenation purposes, just in case

Comment: Using JsHint on the website it works fine for me. Can you reproduce it and give us an executable example?

Comment: @IngoBürk if I turn || "white": true || into false, i get no errors. why?

Comment: Okay, I didn't have `white: true` set and can reproduce it now. I would've thought just putting the `;` in its own line would solve it, but then it says unnecessary semicolon. I think this might be a bug, so you should open an issue over at https://github.com/jshint/jshint/

Comment: I have edited the question such that the code snippet contains only what is needed to reproduce the error and cause no error but this one.

Comment: this looks like a bug.

Comment: Looks like @Luke didn't decide to file the report, so I did now: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1267

Comment: The issue has been closed on jshint since the white option will be removed in the next major release.